# How to show content only after loading the page in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

My code is slow to load in the template and is deforming the html. I wonder how to hide this content until the page has loaded completely.

My code:

```html
{% for movimentacao in movimentacoes %}
                <tr>
                            <td><a href="#">{{ movimentacao.processo }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ movimentacao.descricao }}</td>
                            <td>{{ movimentacao.responsavel }}</td>
                            <td>{{ movimentacao.dt_mov }}</td>
                            <td>{{ movimentacao.cliente1 }}</td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _deforming_, or _hiding_, for that matter? Do you just want it to be hidden, or to not be in the HTML source at all until the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons why your page is slow to load. You should first investigate what causes the slowness, before finding a workaround.

Based on just your code, I would speculate that the number of `movimentacoes` may be too large to show on a single page.

If that is true, you can solve it by reading only a small page of the available data (enough to show on a single screen) and use paging to page through the data.